# How to use Apache POI Workbook to sprarate different data in different excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm new guy to learn Apache POI in java.
My data show like this, I can print all data in one excel.
I want to separate different company data in different excel when I print the excel.
Just like A company data in first page excel, B company data in second page excel and C company data in third page excel.
The excel title can repeat in different excel.

I want all in one sheet in same workbook, and only printed using page break and repeating header row.

Now, I can do like this.

[image]

I want the excel ike this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want data separated into different workbooks? Or into different sheets in same workbook? If so, then what is the problem? If you can put all data into one sheet, you also should be able to put parts of data into different sheets. Or shall all data be in one sheet in same workbook but only **printed** using page breaks and repeating header rows? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clean. I want all in one sheet in same workbook, and only printed using page break and repeating header row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seems to want is [Insert page breaks in a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-move-or-delete-page-breaks-in-a-worksheet-ad3dc726-beec-4a4c-861f-ed640612bdc2#:%7E:text=1%20To%20verify%20that%20drag-and-drop%20is%20enabled%2C%20do,page%20break%20to%20a%20new%20location.%20See%20More) and [Repeat specific rows or columns on every printed page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repeat-specific-rows-or-columns-on-every-printed-page-0d6dac43-7ee7-4f34-8b08-ffcc8b022409#:%7E:text=1%20In%20the%20Rows%20to%20repeat%20at%20top,in%20the%20Rows%20to%20repeat%20at%20top%20box.).

Apache POI provides [Sheet.setRowBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRowBreak-int-) and [Sheet.setRepeatingRows](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRepeatingRows-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress-) to do this.

The following complete example shows how to use those methods.

The data should determine which rows shall be set to perform a page break and which rows shall be repeated on top of every page. In this simple example both is set static to minimize the complexity of the example. Making both dynamic will be a challenge of its own.

This code uses current Apache POI version 5.2.3. It should result in an Excel file where the print preview is exactly as you have shown.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

class CreateExcelRowBreaksRepeatingRows {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
   //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx")
   //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls")
   ) {
       
   // create cell styles on workbook level     
   CellStyle centered = workbook.createCellStyle();
   centered.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER); 
   CellStyle bordered = workbook.createCellStyle();
   bordered.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN); 
   bordered.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN); 
   bordered.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN); 
   bordered.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN); 

   // create data and set on which rows shall be row breaks
   // only static size for this simple example
   Object[][] data = new Object[16][3];
   int[] rowBreaks = new int[2];
   data[0] = new Object[] {"Company name", "Company data1", "Company data2"};
   for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    data[i] = new Object[] {"A", "AX", "AY"};
   }
   rowBreaks[0] = 4;
   for (int i = 5; i < 11; i++) {
    data[i] = new Object[] {"B", "BX", "BY"};
   }
   rowBreaks[1] = 10;
   for (int i = 11; i < 16; i++) {
    data[i] = new Object[] {"C", "CX", "CY"};
   }
   
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 15*256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 15*256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 15*256);

   // create first row - content is outside the defined data
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Total company list");
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2));
   cell.setCellStyle(centered);

   // put data into the sheet
   int startR = 1;
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(startR + r);
    for (int rb = 0; rb < rowBreaks.length; rb++) {
     // shall this row set page break?
     if (rowBreaks[rb] == r) sheet.setRowBreak(row.getRowNum());    
    }   
    for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (r ==0) cell.setCellStyle(bordered);
     Object cellValue = data[r][c];
     if (cellValue instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)cellValue);
     //} else if (cellValue instanceof ToDo) {
      //cell.setCellValue((ToDo)cellValue);
     }
    }
   }
   
   // first two rows shall be repeating rows
   sheet.setRepeatingRows(new CellRangeAddress(0, 1, 0, 0));

   workbook.write(fileout);
   
   if (workbook instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) ((SXSSFWorkbook)workbook).dispose();
   
  }
 }
}
```